# Rehosted Workflow Designer and ToolBox double click

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

1 . I have Toolbox for Activity where I have Activities listed and on right side I have designer where Workflow designer is placed. From my Toolbox I can drag and drop Activites into designer It works fine. Now to increase the usability experience I want to double click on Activity in toolbox and it should be added automatically into desinger within specified "Sequence" activity as the second last activity in sequence workflow ? How can I do this ?

1. I have long running workflow which runs for 3-5  minutes; I want to give flexibility to end user to Cancel/Stop/Abort workflow while workflow is in execution. How can I do this ?
2. I am using Toolbox where I have listed down activities; at top of Toolbox it gives Searchbox; This search box gives search based on first letter; now I want to search for anywhere in the text...

   I am using workflow designer as hosting Workflow and I use WorkflowInvoker to invoke my workflow; so what is best practice to Cancel/Stop executing workflow ?

Comment: Any particular reason you ask lots of questions but never accept an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable double clicking in the ToolboxControl, set the AssociatedDesigner property to the live instance of the WorkflowDesigner.

Answer (score 0):

Might work better if you asked one question per posting...

As for your question on cancel/stop/abort your host application can do this (depending on how you host the workflow).